# htaccess regex remove 3 digits and not next one from url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to remove only the first 3 digits and the first dash from a url:
`/dirname/123-4-filename/`
and leave it as:
`/dirname/4-filename/`

I tried several solutions found here, but they end up removing the number 4 and the following dash, like:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d{3}-.*)/$ /$1/$2/ [L,R=301]`

Thanks

Comment: The rule shouldn't remove anything, because it captures everything and then put it together again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/\d{3}-(\d.*)/$ /$1/$2/ [L,R=301]
```

You were capturing the first 3 digits and the dash, which isn't what you want.  Actually, `\d{3}-.*` was capturing the first 3 digits and dash, and then stopping, counting matching nothing else as being a valid match.

Instead, the regex I gave you will capture everything which comes *after* the first 3 digits and dash.

## Demo here